# Inconsistent decimals in tick labels when using a log axis

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to create a plot with a log y-axis and integer tick labels, but at best I'm getting inconsistent decimals.

The simplest approach gives scientific notation:

```
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

vals = [10, 20, 30]

plt.scatter(vals, vals)
ax = plt.gca()
ax.set_yscale('log')
```

[image: First graph]

Setting the axis's major formatter to scalars still yields some scientific notation:

```
ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(mpl.ticker.ScalarFormatter())
```

[image: Second graph]

And setting the minor formatter on top of that removes scientific notation but leaves inconsistent decimals:

```
ax.yaxis.set_minor_formatter(mpl.ticker.ScalarFormatter())
```

[image: Graph 3]

How can I get all integer tick labels?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As an example, you could use a `StrMethodFormatter` with python's `g` format:

```
fmt = mpl.ticker.StrMethodFormatter("{x:g}")
ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(fmt)
ax.yaxis.set_minor_formatter(fmt)
```

[image]